# Using multiple log4j.properties with a single UDP port for SyslogAppender

Tags: java, maven, log4j, osgi, syslog

I have a maven project where different modules use different log4j.properties files. These have syslog appenders and each of these files opens one UDP port each resulting in opening multiple UDP ports. Is there a way to use a single port for all without opening one for each?

Comment: How is your deployed application structured?

Comment: I have a module for server followed by other modules. the server module uses one log4j.properties and the rest use another which has custom appenders, if that answers your question.

Comment: No it does not. Is it a standalone java application, a WAR based web application, or what?

Comment: Its a maven project using OSGi framework

Comment: As it is an OSGi project it could have been in a single module by design and having a central logging which would only open one port, however, that may defeat part of the modularity wanted. The question is really why does using many ports matter that much? Syslog should be fine with it if it is a comfortable number, and anyway many nowadays use other aggregators to collect and purify logging, such as logstash et al.